# "kubernetes" service in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-service

I have accidentally deleted all the services in my minikube setup, including "kubernetes" service in the default namespace.

But within a few seconds, I noticed the "kubernetes" service created again, automatically.
If I understand corrected, the replica in deployment takes care of only pods, right?
I am wondering how this "kubernetes" service created automatically and what is the use of this service after all.

```
$ kubectl get svc -owide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   13m   <none>

$ kubectl delete svc kubernetes                              
service "kubernetes" deleted

$ kubectl get svc -owide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   3s    <none>
```

Is there a way we can implement the same functionality for our own service?

E.g. whenever it gets deleted, it should be recreated automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Kuberneetes API server will recreate it. You can check below line in the logs of Kubernetes API Server right after you delete the service.

```
Resetting endpoints for master service "kubernetes" to
```

This service is used when you want to interact with Kubernetes API Server from pods using a service account.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/abe6321296123aaba8e83978f7d17951ab1b64fd/pkg/master/controller.go).

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way we can make our own service which will create automatically, whenever if it gets deleted? in YAML way? rather than using Go.

Comment: It’s not magic, the API server watches for any change and updates the object.

Comment: @coderanger Could you please elaborate how can we do the same for our own services? I am from ops side, so I am not a coder (yet) to understand the logic implemented there.

Comment: You would need to make some kind of operator. It uses an API watch to detect changes and reacts to them.